# Gender neutral term for "This Guy" when referring to myself

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, gender-neutral

Is there a gender neutral alternative to "this guy", to refer to yourself in the third person in a gender neutral way?

Example of use:

> Guess who just got a raise? {*This guy!*}

Comment: I think anyone would say {I did!} using the appropriate inflection of excitement.  Or, to avoid using "I"  you could say {We did!} using the royal/editorial we.

Comment: Not in any way an answer but a  relevant point: _guy_ and _guys_ is increasingly used to refer to both men and women. See, for instance, [_How Gender Neutral Is Guys, Really?,_ Slate (2016)](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2016/02/10/the_gender_neutral_use_of_guys_is_on_the_rise_but_it_s_a_slow_rise.html?via=gdpr-consent) The import of that is, of course, a different question (and the subject of the linked article).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a suggestion:

> Guess who just got a raise? **Yours truly**

Comment: "Yours truly" is quite good, but "This fella" isn't gender neutral.

Comment: I would upvote this if it weren't for the first suggestion which is wrong.

Comment: The word "fellow" is perceived as masculine because people has been using it that way, but [etymologically it is not gender specific](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/41853).

Comment: @javorosas "Fellow" != "fella," and especially not in the sense you've linked. Besides, being "perceived as masculine" is what makes it masculine. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy

Comment: @AzorAhai makes sense. I've edited the answer. Thanks for taking the time to point out my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

In light of your example it seems that:

> {**This person!**} would be the actual gender neutral third person
>   form.

But, you can also change it to any gender neutral term appropriate like:

{**This happy one!**}

{**This star employee!**}

{**This past peon!**}

{**This (insert employer name) worker!**}

You get the idea.  And, congratulations if you really did get a promotion.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/peon